# C++ Namespace and Syntax Header File Errors

Tags: c++, header, namespaces, include

I am having the usual errors within header files, as listed below.

```
Error   54  error C3083: 'Resources': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type   e:\users\nkosi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\directx games\direct2d\dx2dhelper\dx2dhelper\sprite.h  28  1   DX2DHelper
Error   55  error C2039: 'DX2DImage' : is not a member of 'DX2DHelper'  e:\users\nkosi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\directx games\direct2d\dx2dhelper\dx2dhelper\sprite.h  28  1   DX2DHelper
Error   56  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'DX2DImage'  e:\users\nkosi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\directx games\direct2d\dx2dhelper\dx2dhelper\sprite.h  28  1   DX2DHelper
Error   57  error C3083: 'Resources': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type   e:\users\nkosi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\directx games\direct2d\dx2dhelper\dx2dhelper\sprite.h  32  1   DX2DHelper
Error   58  error C2039: 'DX2DImage' : is not a member of 'DX2DHelper'  e:\users\nkosi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\directx games\direct2d\dx2dhelper\dx2dhelper\sprite.h  32  1   DX2DHelper
Error   59  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  e:\users\nkosi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\directx games\direct2d\dx2dhelper\dx2dhelper\sprite.h  32  1   DX2DHelper
Error   60  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   e:\users\nkosi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\directx games\direct2d\dx2dhelper\dx2dhelper\sprite.h  32  1   DX2DHelper
Error   61  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'GameBase'   e:\users\nkosi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\directx games\direct2d\dx2dhelper\dx2dhelper\systemclass.h 30  1   DX2DHelper
```

However, for the life of me, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I know I'm probably missing a semi-colon or something, but I really can't figure it out. All the header files are below.

DX2DHelper.h

```
#include "targetver.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEANheaders
// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>

#include <D2D1.h>
#include <D2D1Helper.h>
#include <wincodec.h>
#include <D2DBaseTypes.h>
#include <D2Derr.h>

#define DLEX __declspec(dllexport)

#include "GameBase.h"
#include "SystemClass.h"
#include "DX2DImage.h"
#include "Sprite.h"
```

SystemClass.h

```
#ifndef SYSTEMCLASS_H
#define SYSTEMCLASS_H

#include "DX2DHelper.h"

namespace DX2DHelper
{
    namespace Core
    {
        class SystemClass;
        struct WindowOptions;

        struct DLEX WindowOptions {};

        class DLEX SystemClass
        {
        public:
            bool Initialize(WindowOptions options, HINSTANCE hInst);
            void Run(GameBase* game, DX2DInitOptions options);
        private:
            WindowOptions options;    
        };
    }
}
#endif
```

DX2DImage.h

```
#ifndef DX2DIMAGE_H
#define DX2DIMAGE_H

#include "DX2DHelper.h"

namespace DX2DHelper
{
    namespace Resources
    {
        class DX2DImage;
        class DX2DImageLoader;

        class DLEX DX2DImageLoader
        {
        public:
            HRESULT LoadFromFile(char* filePath, DX2DImage* image);
        };

        class DLEX DX2DImage
        {
        public:
            friend class DX2DImageLoader;
        };
    }
}

#endif
```

Sprite.h

```
#ifndef SPRITE_H
#define SPRITE_H

#include "DX2DHelper.h"

namespace DX2DHelper
{
    namespace GameComponents
    {
        class DLEX Sprite
        {
        public:
            void SetImage(DX2DHelper::Resources::DX2DImage* image);

        private:
            DX2DHelper::Resources::DX2DImage* image;
        };
    }
}
#endif
```

GameBase.h

```
#ifndef GAMEBASE_H
#define GAMEBASE_H

#include "DX2DHelper.h"

namespace DX2DHelper
{
    namespace Core
    {
        class DLEX GameBase
        {
        public:
            friend class SystemClass;

            HRESULT Initialize(HINSTANCE hInst, HWND winHandle, struct DX2DInitOptions options);
        };

        struct DLEX DX2DInitOptions {};
    }
}
#endif
```

If anyone could figure out the mistakes, I would be very grateful. I've been looking at the same files for probably close to an hour, hour and a half now, and I just can't fix it.

Comment: Please give us a http://sscce.org/. Otherwise, I can almost ensure that no one will be willing to read *all* of that. Break it down into smaller pieces. And sometimes, this may even help you find the answer yourself.

Comment: In addition to @Drise's comment, I'd say that you should try and look at your own code for more than an hour before asking the internet at large for a solution. Debugging it yourself (and following the steps in Drise's link) will teach you a lot about programming. Not to say that you wouldn't still have a question after that--but perhaps you should put a bit more time into it first.

Comment: I hate such kind of questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your headers have (many) include cycle(s).  For example, `DX2DHelper.h` includes `Sprite.h` includes `DX2DHelper.h`.  This is probably what's causing your errors.  This code isn't Java, and those aren't import statements: `#include` cycles totally kill compiles, even if you don't get a compile error specifically stating so.  Pick an acyclic order for your header files.

I'd suggest that `DX2DHelper.h` not have any of the includes at the bottom.  `Sprite.h` could include `DX2DImage.h`.

Where your objects have cyclic dependencies (as is the case with `SystemClass` and `GameBase`, for example), you'll need another solution.  Forward declare the dependent class without giving its full declaration, e.g. in `SystemClass.h` you might add somewhere early:

```
namespace DX2DHelper { namespace Core { class DLEX GameBase; } }
```

and similarly in in `GameBase.h`:

```
namespace DX2DHelper { namespace Core { class DLEX SystemClass;} }
```

This can even be a good idea when there aren't cyclic object dependencies involved -- its usually an easy way around the type of header hell you've run into here.  Of course, to get everything to compile, you'll probably need to `#include` the appropriate headers in the corresponding implementation files.  But, assuming you don't `#include` any of your `.cpp`/`.cc` files, this should allow everything to compile without the `#include` hell you've gotten yourself into.

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix it. I took your advice and made each class's header file only include exactly what it needed, instead of including DX2DHelper.h, which had everything. I was under the impression the header protectors at the top of each file would stop the include loops, so I didn't really think that was the problem, but I guess I was wrong. Thank you very much for your help.